# MongoDB Documentation (Projection vs. Query)

Tags: mongodb

Was checking the MongoDB docs yesterday and noticed a lot of their operators have two entries, one under [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) and one under [query](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/).

What's the difference between the two?  They seem to pretty much cover the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query is actually querying for records whereas projection is the projection of document fields.

Another way of putting this is to say projection is `SELECT` in SQL and query is `WHERE`.

Lets look at an example ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/ ):

```
db.users.find(
    { sessions: {$elemMatch:{session_id: 23}} }, 
    { sessions:{$elemMatch:{session_id: 23}} }
)
```

This query uses $elemMatch to match a element in the `sessions` field of a `user` document while using the very same operator for projection of that found `session`.

Of course in reality you wouldn't write this query like this since you could just do `sessions.$` for the projection part but I wrote it out this way to show you in a more complete manner.

Comment: Ahhh, so when you limit the fields you get back from Mongo, you can use $gt, $elemMatch, etc. for more complex logic.  Was about to say the SQL example didn't help, then it finally dawned on me what you were talking about.  Thanks for the help!